# Is there any way to create object of method-local inner class in main method?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

I was wondering if there is any way to create a method-local inner class object in main() method with the help of Outerclass object.

```
public class Outerclass {
   // instance method of the outer class 
   void my_Method() {
      int num = 23;

      // method-local inner class
      class MethodInner_Demo {
         public void print() {
            System.out.println("This is method inner class "+num);     
         }   
      } // end of inner class
       
      // Accessing the inner class
      MethodInner_Demo inner = new MethodInner_Demo();
      inner.print();
   }
   
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Outerclass outer = new Outerclass();
      outer.my_Method();           
   }
}
```

Edit-1:
I was exploring the way to instantiate a method-local inner class in the main method ( I know the method-local inner class is not visible to the main method) but still, is there any workaround?

```
public class Outerclass {
   // instance method of the outer class 
   void my_Method() {
      int num = 23;

      // method-local inner class
      class MethodInner_Demo {
         public void print() {
            System.out.println("This is method inner class "+num);     
         }   
      } // end of inner class   
   }
   
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Outerclass outer = new Outerclass();
      //inner-class object is created while calling my_Method()
      // TBH IDK how to do this 
      outer.my_Method().new MethodInner_Demo();
       
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare the class within a function if you want to access it from other functions?

Comment: @akuzminykh Probably so it could access local variable `num`. That of course then leads to the question of which `num` would be used if the class was instantiated from another method.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, please see edit1.

Comment: @akuzminykh, to answer your question, I'm exploring the possibilities on flexibilities of method local inner class to reuse the pre-written classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the method local class is invisible to `main`. However, you can create that instance and pass it to `main`.

```
public class OuterClass {
    Object createInnerClass() {
        int num = 23;
        class InnerClass {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "I'm InnerClass. num=" + num;
            }
        }
        return new InnerClass();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
        Object obj = outer.createInnerClass();
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

output:

```
I'm InnerClass. num=23
```

Answer (score 1):

Class `MethodInner_Demo` is a ***local*** class, not an *inner* class, since it is declared in the body of a method. See e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html).

A local class can only be seen by code in the method where is it declared.

If you want to be able to create an instance of the class from another method, then you need to move the class outside the method, so it becomes an actual *inner* class.

You can then create an instance, assuming you're "authorized", as defined by the `public`, `protected`, and `private` access modifiers. You do that by qualifying the `new` operator with an instance of the outer class.

In your case, we also need to add a field to carry the value of `num`.

```java
public class Outerclass {
   // instance method of the outer class 
   void my_Method() {
      int num = 23;
       
      // Accessing the inner class
      Inner_Demo inner = new Inner_Demo(num);
      inner.print();
   }

   // inner class
   class Inner_Demo {
      private final int num;
      Inner_Demo(int num) {
         this.num = num;
      }
      public void print() {
         System.out.println("This is inner class "+num);
      }   
   } // end of inner class
   
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Outerclass outer = new Outerclass();
      outer.my_Method();
      
      // Accessing the inner class
      int num = 42;
      Inner_Demo inner = outer.new Inner_Demo(num);
      inner.print();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Andreas, For your efforts but I was looking for a way to instantiate a method- local inner class within the main method. (which is practically not possible as a method- local inner class is not visible to the main method).